# show that $c=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}C_G(g).$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is a finite group and $c$ is the number of equivalence classes of the conjugation
relation in $G$, show that
$$c=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}C_G(g).$$

I have in my hands: $G$ can be partitioned  into conjugacy classes.

So $G=\bigcup_{g\in G} Cl(g)$ so

$|G|=\sum_{g\in G}|Cl(g)|=\sum_{g\in G}|G|/|C_G(g)|$.

Given $c$ is the number of conjugacy classes so $$c=\sum_{g\in G}|G|/|C_G(g)|\Rightarrow \frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|C_G(g)|.$$

How to prove $$c=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}C_G(g)?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma

Answer (score 0):

Burnside says that the number of orbits of the action of $G$ on a set $X$ (everything finite) is given by
$$ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} |X_g|,$$
where $X_g = \{x\in X\mid g\cdot x=x\}$ is the set of fixed points under $g\in G$.

In your case, the set of fixed points under $g\in G$ is given by $C_G(g) = \{h\in H\mid g\cdot h = g^{-1}hg=h\}$, the centralizer of $g\in G$.

Hence, $ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} |C_G(g)|.$

Comment: Please see my edits I found $c$ in fraction.